# Android AlarmManager AM and PM Difference

Tags: android, timezone, alarmmanager

I am creating alarm app. I am using following code.It is working very well but it start alarm alert on wrong time. It is not differentiate alarm between am and pm Example; if I set alarm for 10am and currently 10pm in device then also my alert activity starts. How can I solve this, thanks.

```
Calendar timeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
timeCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());


@Override
public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout radialPickerLayout, int i, int i2) {
    timeCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, i2);
    timeCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i);

    if (i == 0) {
        timeCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,0);
    } else if (i < 12) {
        timeCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,0);
    } else if (i == 12) {
        timeCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,1);
    } else {
        timeCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,1);
    }
    updateLabel();
}
```

Function:

```
   private void setAlarm() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("type", "Alarm");
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
    int sonid = db.sonId("alarm");
    b.putInt("notify_id", sonid);
    db.close();
    myIntent.putExtras(b);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, sonid, myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: why you are setting AM/PM again in your calendar, by doing this timeCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i), you already are setting time to a particular hour in day e.g 1 or 19 o'clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enjoy Full Code**

Call **openTimePickerDialog()** in buttonclick or wherever you want to set alarm;

```
private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                onTimeSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), is24r);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");

        timePickerDialog.show();

    }
```

**This is timer listener ;**

OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
        // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    setAlarm(calSet);
}
```

};

**setAlarm() ;**

```
 private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

        textAlarmPrompt.setText("\n\n***\n" + "Alarm is set "
                + targetCal.getTime() + "\n" + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);

    }
```

**Reciver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context k1, Intent k2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText(k1, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

**In manifest :**

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I solve the problem with your code.
✓✓

Comment: I tried but I have no enough reputation to upvote. Thank you for your help again

Comment: Its OK, sorry I'm new :)

Comment: Yeah No problem ,Thanks